# How can I convert a DataTable to a GeoDatabaseTable

Tags: c#, geoprocessing, esri-geodatabase

I have a DataTable full of "stops" and I want to convert it into a table that can be GeoCoded. However, I am getting an error when I try to execute it.

The Message: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

The Error Code: -2147467259

```
public static void DataTableToGeoDataBaseTable(DataTable inTable, string outPath, string outName)
    {

        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        dTable = inTable;

        Geoprocessor GP = new Geoprocessor();

        // Create the tool process object.
        ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.CopyRows copyrowsTool = new
            ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.CopyRows();

        // Set parameter values.
        copyrowsTool.in_rows = dTable;
        copyrowsTool.out_table = outPath + "\\" + outName;    //"Z:\\Projects\\Project\\NewTable"

        // Execute the tool. 
        GP.Execute(copyrowsTool, null);  //ERROR HRESULT E_FAIL HAPPENS HERE
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

I have also tried this version

```
public static void DataTableToGeoDataBaseTable(DataTable inTable, string outPath, string outName)
    {

        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        dTable = inTable;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.TableToTable tableToTable = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.TableToTable();
        tableToTable.in_rows = dTable;
        tableToTable.out_name = outName;
        tableToTable.out_path = outPath;

        Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
        gp.Execute(tableToTable, null);

    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to contain the exact error message(s)

Comment: @Vince Added the error message and code

Comment: Does the same thing work with python? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-rows.htm

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is you are mixing .Net objects with ArcObject objects. The [CopyRows.in_rows](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#/in_rows_Property/004700002w83000000/) takes an ArcObjects tables but you are providing it with a [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a .Net object.